# Angular ng-show directive doesn't work for button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have angular.js web application and btn-group in there like:

```
<div class="btn-group>
  <button class="btn btn-default hidden-xs">....</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default hidden-xs">....</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default hidden-xs">....</button>
</div>
```

I want to hide one of button and added:

```
<button ng-show="show_button">....</button>
```

And in controller

`$scope.show_button = false;`

But i see button. Why? `ng-show` works for whole `btn-group` but not for one button.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUl9yYcZUDnuUneh6Cn1?p=preview) example for you. It works for me in `btn-group`.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem using Angular v1.2.2.

It appears that Bootstrap's style rules for .hidden-xs:

```
.hidden-xs { display: block !important; }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .hidden-xs { display: none !important; }
}
```

override the style rules from Angular's (v1.2.2) injected inline stylesheet (prepended instead of appended to the head) for .ng-hide (presumably, .ng-show as well).

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak,
.ng-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

For lack of better solution at the moment, add the angular stylesheet or specific rules that you need to your document, stylesheet or in some other fashion. (Then check for style rule changes if you change versions of Angular). If anyone has a more appropriate solution, feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

bootstraps' `.hidden-xs` class adds `display:block` for visible elemets which breaks angular's `ng-show` and `ng-hide` classes.

Instead, use a custom `.my-hidden-xs` class:

```
// my-style.css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .my-hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

// index.html
<button class="btn btn-default my-hidden-xs" ng-show="show_button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. Finally I found that I set the style "visibility: hidden" in my own CSS file to the div. So no matter how I change the expression in ng-show, div is always hidden. That means the visibility style in your own style is always applied, angularjs will never change this css property value. To use ng-show/ng-hide the first thing you need to make sure is that you do NOT add any show/hide style to DOM element, just hand over the control to angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `ng-show`/`ng-hide` with `ng-if`. 
Should do the trick :)