# why does Angular ng-cloak override my ng-show even with custom directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to hide my layout page while logging in, I have ng-show set to a boolean that when there is a successful log in gets set to true. No matter what I do the layout page will not show its self. I followed the answer from this [Angular ng-show directive doesn't work for button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235516/angular-ng-show-directive-doesnt-work-for-button) but I still don't get the page to show. When I look in the dev tools I can see that my custom style is being applied

Html Code:

```
<div class="my-hidden-xs container" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
```

CSS:

```
.my-hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Controller:

```
function LogInController($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;     
    $scope.signOn = function () {
        $http.post('http://localhost:a location on my backend').then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.token) {
                $scope.$apply.isLoggedIn = true;
                $state.go('main'); 
                //...
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am new to angular but have used hide and show before without this problem.

Comment: `$scope.$apply.isLoggedIn = true;`? Maybe `$scope.isLoggedIn = true;`

Comment: @dsfq I tried just $scope as well with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change your css you have display: none !important and i can not see any code that changes it on the success function
You can use something like this:

```
<div class="container {{checkVisible(isLoggedIn)}}">
```

in controller

```
$scope.checkVisible()
{
 if(isLoggedIn)
      return '';
 else
      return 'my-hidden-xs';   
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be the issue. Thank you @Utku

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change you logic. Don't apply `my-hidden-xs` class by default, but instead use `ngClass` directive:

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{'my-hidden-xs': !isLoggedIn}">
```

Then when needed you set flag to `true`:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = true;
```

Comment: This looks like the right path, but I am still getting the same result, I think I need to read the ngDocs also. thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

wait.
ng-cloak doesn't overrides your ng-show, what happens is with you define display:none two times, and ng-show doesn't will influence on your class definition.

Only change your DIV line to:

```
<div class="container" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
```

and, of course, if your page has a flick, insert an external div with ng-cloak

```
<div ng-cloak>
    <div class="container" ng-show="isLoggedIn"> 
    ...
```

Comment: But, whatever, I would try to use ngRoute, ngView or ngInclude, because I don't like to load all page and hide it, if the user is not logged.

Answer (score 0):

All directives have it's own executing priorities, I couldn't find details in docs, but you can look into source code to find it, e.g.: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.2/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L215

You can set priority of your directive the same way as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this, I made a function in the config that sets the is logged in property so instead of 
    ng-show="isLoggedIn"

I have
    ng-show="isLoggedIn()"

I then call that function passing true to it when I verify my JWT, its a little bit of a hack but it works and I can keep going, I have a feeling that when I get into the validation of the JWTS on the front end a bit more I will abstract some of this into a service.